# How to use a spreadsheet or equivalent to store lists in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv

I'm looking for a way to store my lists in a spreadsheet so that I can read to check if an account exists as well as write to so I can create new accounts.

The example below only has usernames and passwords but I also ask for email in my create account portion of my code so that too would be stored in the spreadsheet.

Also, I'm curious if anybody has any tips about making this more secure.

```
userlist = ["user1","user2","user3"]
passlist = ["pass1","pass2","pass3"]

username = str(input("\n[Login to an existing account]\nUsername:"))
password = str(input("Password:"))
    if username in userlist:
        if password == passlist[userlist.index(username)]:
            logged_in = True
```

Comment: Tips to make this more secure: Don't store this data in a spreadsheet. Use a "real" database and encrypt your stuff!

Comment: This part won't actually be specific to python. There are a variety of database management systems out there to chose from, each with their own nuances and security measures. Since you're new to this, it'll probably be easiest for you to start off with SQLite3. Check it out, and read up on how to encrypt your database here: https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki

Comment: Were you able to resolve your issue with "looking for a way to store my lists in a spreadsheet?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purposes, it would be easier to read/write to a CSV (comma-separated values) file than to use a spreadsheet. Note that all modern spreadsheet applications can read in CSV files and display them as spreadsheets, as well as export spreadsheets as CSV files.

```
import csv

# reading the lists from an existing CSV
with open('usernames_and_passwords.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    userlist = [row[0] for row in reader]
    passlist = [row[1] for row in reader]

# writing the Python lists to a CSV (overwrites existing files)
with open('usernames_and_passwords.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(zip(userlist, passlist))
```

### However:

Like @JoshuaSchlichting mentioned above in the comments, spreadsheets are not a very secure way of storing user information. In general, user passwords should **never** be stored **anywhere** on the server side of applications. Applications typically store a non-reversible cryptographic hash of each user password which the application would then use to compare with a newly calculated hash when a user enters their password. This is to prevent password info from being compromised should the server ever be hacked.

For the purposes of learning, using your existing methodology is fine, just don't use it in a public application.

Comment: While I would also choose the csv over a spreadsheet (and I also appreciate the shout-out *tips fedora*), the question specifically asks for how to read/write to spreadsheets, not "what are better alternatives to writing to spreadsheets." ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Touché @JoshuaSchlichting

Comment: for readability, you might want to put the logic that deals with individual login actions in separate functions. For example, you could have a `create_account()` handling the things under `if login_option == str(2):`

Comment: @nmog Don't take it as a "diss" at all. csv is definitely the better way to go, as excel is the devil. (a databse is THE way to go) It's just not the answer to the question. Sending much programmer love to you for your contribution to SO on a Saturday afternoon!

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting Haha thanks! The same to you! I definitely agree, a database is a much better option.

Comment: Try using print statements to print out the values of userlist and passlist at different places in the code to see if their values are being correctly updated.

Answer (score 3):

Hunter, if you're serious about using a spreadsheet for doing this sort of thing, check out [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html) and [OpenPyXL](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), but please consider using a "real" database as we discussed in the comments!

From the OpenPyXl docs:

**Reading from a sheet**

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='large_file.xlsx', read_only=True)
ws = wb['big_data']

for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)
```

Using that method above, you should be able to do something like this with your password checking:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='userpasslist.xlsx', read_only=True)
ws = wb['userpassworksheet']

for row in ws.rows:
    # assuming 1st column contains user names
    if row[0].value == username:
        # assuming 2nd column contains matching password
        if row[1].value == password:
            print("Success! Password matches! Do something here!")
        else:
            print("booo! Wrong password! Now git' out!")
        break
```

[**From the XlsxWriter docs: Writing to a sheet**](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html)

**How you can apply this:**

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('userpassbook.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
users = (
    ['user1', 'password'],
    ['user2', 'password'],
    ['user3', 'password'],
    ['user4', 'password']
)

# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for username, password in (users):
    worksheet.write(row, col, username)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, password)
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```